# Is it possible to get autotools for a 64bit Windows 10

Tags: windows, 64-bit, autotools

I am trying to build an old program and have to do it on windows. In the build instructions i am required to use autoreconf and therefore i need to have autotools.

I have tried searching for it for a while and installing cygwin or gnuWin32 but I have come to a conclusion that those bins only work for a 32 bit operating system.Is there any way I can get those binaries for a 64 bit system?

Comment: It is surprising and a bit dubious that the build instructions require running `autoreconf`.  Sometimes that is indeed necessary for an Autotools project, but it is not a normal, routine, or wholly safe endeavor.

Comment: With that said, even if you don't run `autoreconf`, you probably do need a more posix-like environment than Windows provides by default.  For that, you probably want [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), which also does a fine job of hosting [Mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).